# Проверка первого нажатия на кнопку

Tags: java, android

Как проверить, нажата ли кнопка в первый раз?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Устанавливаете флаг нажатия и проверяете его - нажималась кнопка или нет. При нажатии на кнопку флагу присваиваете значение `true`:

```
boolean isPressed = false; // флаг проверки нажатия, false - не нажималась
....
if (isPressed) {     //проверка нажималась или нет

 // действия, когда кнопка нажималась хотя бы раз

}
....  
@Override 
public void onClick(View view) {
 isPressed = true;
 .... // другие функции при нажатии на кнопку
}
```

Если первое нажатие необходимо запомнить и после закрытия приложения, записываете значение `isPressed` в `SharedPreferences` и при старте читаете сохранённое значение, в `onClick()` записываете результат:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

          //Получаем значение флага. 
          //Если ни разу не нажималась, то такой записи нет и значение по дефолту false

    boolean isPressed = sp.getBoolean("isPressed", false);


    if (isPressed) {

        // действия , если кнопка нажималась хотя бы раз

    }

   @Override 
     public void onClick(View view) { // обработчик клика по кнопке,которую проверяем
       Editor e = sp.edit();
        e.putBoolean("isPressed", true);
        e.commit(); 

     .... // другие функции при нажатии на кнопку
   }
```

Второе решение наиболее универсально, не требует дополнительного сохранения в `onSaveInstanceState()` и помнит состояние и после закрытия приложения.

Answer (score 1):

Если надо проверить это на конкретном экране (**Activity**) то можно так:

1) Завести переменную типа **boolean**, коя на момент запуска **Activity** будет равна **false**

2) При нажатии на кнопку проверять её значение и если она **false** (т.е. кнопка нажата впервые), то присвоить ей true. Теперь каждой следующее нажатие будет явно не первым.

3) Сохранять\ восстанавливать значение этой переменной в **onSaveInstanceState**() и **onRestoreInstanceState**() методах активити.

Если же вдруг надо определить первое нажатии кнопки вообще, то указанную выше переменную можно хранить в SharedPreferences или на сервере.