# Как выполнить условие, если кнопка нажималась?

Tags: android

Как выполнить условие,если кнопка нажималась ранее?

Например, `If (button.кликнута) do smth`.

Comment: Вам надо выполнить действие прямо в момент нажатия кнопки или уже потом проверить, нажималась ли эта кнопка?

Comment: Нужно выполнить действие после нажатия кнопки.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проверка первого нажатия на кнопку](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420643/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо завести boolean переменную и в неё записывать состояние "нажата/не нажата" при нажатии на кнопку.

Потом эту переменную проверять.

В классе кнопки такого свойства нет.

Comment: Ага, а как записать состояние при нажатии?

Comment: Просто установите переменной значение true или false;

Answer (score 2):

Странно что такого решения не предложили:

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {
                    //yourLogicHere();
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: вообще у кнопки есть `OnClickListener` который в данном случае более уместен и об этом, конечно, многим известно, но дело в том, что неясен сам вопрос. Пока автор не ответит на комментарий под вопросом, писать что то не имеет смысла.

Answer (score 1):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // do smth
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

А вообще для таких целей

> If (button.кликнута) do smth

есть специальный тип кнопок [`ToggleButton`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html), у которой как раз таки и есть метод `isChecked()`