# Возможно ли повесить разные события на одну кнопку

Tags: java, android, button, события, android-on-click

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при первом нажатии на кнопку совершались одни действия, а при повторном нажатии - другие? Если да, то как это сделать? 
Например: нажимаю на кнопку - 1, кнопка - 2 становится неактивной, нажимаю еще раз на кнопку - 1, кнопка - 2 опять становится активной.

Если конкретнее, как создать условие внутри обработчика кнопки, чтобы он отслеживал первое это нажатие или повторное, и исходя из результата выбирал те или иные действия?

Comment: Заведите переменную `boolean` полем вашего класса и на основании её значения выполняйте необходимые действия со второй кнопкой в обработчике нажатия на первую кнопку. Т.е. при нажатии меняете значение переменной на противоположное. А в теле обработчика нажатия на первую кнопку через условный оператор `if` и значение переменной выполняете действия

Comment: Почитай про boolean в java. А вообще @Chubatiy, дал ответ на твой вопрос

Comment: @Chubatiy Спасибо за ответ! Я понял что нужно сделать. Да, про boolean знаю конечно же. Просто не додумался, что все можно так просто сделать. Думал может уже есть какой-то метод для этого.

Comment: Оформите свои решения в виде ответа (ответить на собственный вопрос), а не пишите их в вопросе - вопрос только для описания проблемы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для решения задачи в вопросе не требуется отслеживания очередности нажатия:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    boolean isEnabled;
    Button button1;
    Button button2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
         button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
         button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        button2.setEnabled(isEnabled);
        isEnabled = !isEnabled;
    }
}
```

В более общем случае вы можете аналогично использовать состояние флага `isEnabled` для определения требующихся действий и задавать в зависимости от его состояния через тернарный оператор или оператор `if` нужные действия. Устанавливать состояние этого флага можно и из других методов. Так же можно использовать и переменную типа `int` вместо `boolean`, если требуется более двух состояний.

Если требуется сохранить текущее состояние после выхода из приложения, то это состояние нужно сохранять в `SharedPreferences`. Логика анологична [этому ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/420647/177345).